# Как переключать фрагменты с помощью анимации в Navigation drawer используя Navigation components

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Всем привет. В приложении использую Navigation components  и Navigation drawer. Нужно при нажатии на кнопку в navigation drawer фрагмент переключался с помощью анимации. Как это делать в navigation components я знаю но только если при переходе на другой фрагмент нужно нажать обычную кнопку, а вот как это реализовать с использованием navigation drawer  я не могу разобраться.

вот код MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.nav_food_text_analysis,
            R.id.nav_recipe_analysis
        ), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

вот код navigation xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_food_text_analysis">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_food_text_analysis"
        android:name="com.example.nutritionfacts.ui.foodTextAnalysis.FoodAnalysisFragment"
        android:label="Food analysis"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_food_text_analysis" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_food_text_analysis_to_nav_recipe_analysis"
            app:destination="@id/nav_recipe_analysis"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/enter_from_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/exit_to_right"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/enter_from_right"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/exit_to_right" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_recipe_analysis"
        android:name="com.example.nutritionfacts.ui.recipeAnalysis.RecipeAnalysisFragment"
        android:label="Recipe analysis"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_recipe_analysis" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_recipe_analysis_to_nav_food_text_analysis2"
            app:destination="@id/nav_food_text_analysis"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/enter_from_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/exit_to_right"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/enter_from_right"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/exit_to_right" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для добавления анимации к переходам между фрагментами надо создать объект NavOptions

```
private val navOptions by lazy {
        NavOptions.Builder()
            .setLaunchSingleTop(true)
            .setEnterAnim(R.anim.enter_from_right)
            .setExitAnim(R.anim.exit_to_right)
            .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.enter_from_right)
            .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.exit_to_right)
}
```

А так же добавить NavigationItemSelectedListener для NavView после всех настроек

```
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
                navController.navigate(item.itemId, null, navOptions.build())
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers()
                true
}
```

Если вам нужны различные анимации для разных фрагментов, то в setNavigationItemSelectedListener выбирайте нужный через `when(item.itemId)` и назначайте ему свой набор анимаций через NavOptions

Comment: У меня это все есть. Вы сейчас написали как использовать Navigation drawer совместно с Navigation components, фрагменты будут просто переключаться, а мне нужно чтобы фрагменты переключались с помощью анимации

Comment: Извините, не правильно вас понял. Исправил свой ответ.

Comment: анимации лучше добавлять в xml в nav_graph а не в коде. и не надо никаких проверок when(item.itemId). в nav_graph для каждого перехода указываются анимации для него

Comment: @Cypher Проблема в том, что когда вы передали управление навигацией шторки, она игнорирует анимации, задаваемые в разметке. Вы можете проверить это создав проект со стандартной DrawerActivity.

Comment: @blind.falcon понятно

Comment: @blind.falcon Я точно так же реализовал это. Я думаю это единственный вариант, других вариантов я не нашел